# How to rewrite all url using .htaccess in laravel

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a laravel app. In my app there are some products which are already indexed on google.

I can change products URL through Routes but when a user comes using the google search engine there is a server error because I have changed all product URLs through routes.

Now I am trying to redirect the old URL to the newer by .htaccess

The original URL is `www.xxx.com/product/samsung-galaxy-a90.php`

I want to redirect it `to www.xxx.com/samsung-galaxy-a90`

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) product/$1.php [NC,L]
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('product/{proslug}.php', 'PostController@singlepro')
    ->name('singlepro');
```

Now what is the right .htaccess code to do this?

Comment: With the `RewriteRule` and `Route` you have shown, what happens? Instead of using `.htaccess`, why not keep things simple and just [use Laravel's `redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the `.htaccess`, you can do all with laravel `routes`, e.g.:

```php
Route::get('/product/{proslug}.php', function ($proslug) {
    return redirect('/'.$proslug, 301); // Moved Permanently
    return redirect('/'.$proslug, 302); // Moved Temporarily
});
// Other routes
// Last route because is a catch all route
Route::get('/{proslug}', 'PostController@singlepro')
    ->name('singlepro');
```

You only need to put the `'singlepro'` route as the last one of your routes because is a `catch all route`.

With that routes in place every request to `www.xxx.com/product/samsung-galaxy-a90.php` will be redirected **temporary** (code **302**) or **permanently** (code **301**) to `www.xxx.com/samsung-galaxy-a90`  and to the `PostController` `singlepro()` function with parameter `$proslug`, e.g.:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function singlepro($proslug)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to check **AllowOverride**  if it is **None** so set it to  **All** like

```
<Directory /var/www/project_folder/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In addition, make sure that the rewrite module is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```